# Sorting orders by name rather than by order number

Tags: commerce

On my orders page you can search orders by order number only - how do I change this so I can also sort by name, date, ect. When we have customers come in that do not know their order number, we cannot search for their name! The name column on our orders table also does not sort correctly, you can sort by most recent or oldest date, but you cannot sort names alphabetically. Not sure how to change this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using views to build your table, take a look at the table settings. In there you can set default sort, and there is a checkbox to make columns sortable.

Comment: I have done this - thanks for your help. In the header before my table it says specify order by order number, then you type in the number, then you search for it. I changed this so you can search for either order number or order id, but is there a way to search for name or date, do you know?